# Bounded variation and differentiability implies absolute continuity

Tags: real-analysis

**Problem:** Let $f$ be a real-valued function everywhere differentiable function on $[0,1]$. If $f$ is of bounded variation on $[0,1]$, then it is absolutely continuous on $[0,1]$.

<s>This follows from the Banach–Zaretsky theorem, the mean value theorem, and the observation that Lipschitz functions take sets of measure zero to measure zero.</s>

This follows from the Banach–Zaretsky theorem, which I will state it here for convenience:

> Let $F$ be a function of bounded variation on $[a,b]$, then the
>   following are equivalent:
>
> (i) F is absolutely continuous on $[a,b]$.
>
> (ii) $m(A) = 0 \implies m(F(A)) = 0$ for all measurable $A \subset [a,b]$.

The proof of this statement along with the posed problem can be found [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=ErtmdgxSxA8C&pg=PA225&lpg=PA225&dq=Banach%20Zarecki%20Theorem&source=bl&ots=2RJFiaCavC&sig=V__u-QQPSSurVY826euuHOaoiPw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=jwbDUoSiOLHMsQTW_IHoDA&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=Banach%20Zarecki%20Theorem&f=false).

**Question:** The original problem appeared in a qualifying exam a few months ago, and I am very curious if there is an alternative approach here for an examinee who might not have been aware of Banach–Zaretsky theorem. Any suggestion?

Comment: I don't think your argument works, you're proving the much stronger statement that $f$ is Lipschitz continuous, but a counterexample to this is given by $f(x)=x^{3/2}\sin(1/x)$ which is everywhere differentiable with integrable derivative (hence AC) but it's not Lipschitz.

Comment: Another thing: In the Banach-Zaretsky theorem you need $F$ to be a-priori continuous (as in the book), since otherwise $F=1_{[0,1/2]}$ is a counterexample.

Answer (score -1):

If f is differentiable everywhere on $(0,1)$ we can say $$f(1)-f(0) =\int^1_0 f'(x)dx \ \ (*)$$ If we knew that $f$ is a monotone function, (*) would immediately imply that $f$ is AC. However we know that $f$ is of bounded variation, thus can be written as the difference of two monotonically increasing functions on $[0,1]$ : $$f(x)=[f(x)+{TV}(f_{[0,x]})] - TV(f_{[0,x]})$$ Where $TV(f_{[0,x]})$ is the total variation function, which is differentiable everywhere on $[0,1]$, since it is monotone on $[0,1]$ and by Lebesgue's theorem is differentiable.

Comment: Doesn't equation $(*)$ only hold if we already know that $f$ is AC?

Comment: There is another theorem that says: if (*) holds and if $f$ is a monotone function, then $f$ is AC.

Comment: If we have that : Sum of two AC functions is AC, we're done.

Comment: @Roozbeh-unity, I still don't understand how you justify $(*)$. I think that's where the subtlety really lies.

Comment: Maybe my solution is not perfectly correct. What I thought is : f is differentiable everywhere ("NOT" a.e.) on $[0,1]$ therefore it is continuous on the whole closed bounded interval $[0,1]$. Now, I copy from Wikipedia (cuz I doubted my mind for a second)  if f is a continuous real-valued function defined on a closed interval [a, b], then, once an antiderivative F of f is known, the definite integral of f over that interval is given by
$\int^b_a  f(x)dx = F(b) - F(a)$.

Comment: But only $f$ is continuous, not its derivative (which is what you use).

Comment: @Jose27 Well spotted, thanks ! But Let's look at 2nd fundamental theorem of calculus (Newton–Leibniz axiom), from Wiki :
Let f and F be real-valued functions defined on a closed interval [a, b] such that the derivative of F is f. That is, f and F are functions such that for all x in [a, b],
F'(x) = f(x).\ 
If f is Riemann integrable on [a, b] then
$\int^b_a f(x)dx = F(b) - F(a)$.
The is stronger than the Fundamental theorem of Calculus it does not assume that f is continuous.

Comment: If $f$ is Riemann integrable then $F$ is Lipschitz (since $f$ is bounded) and there is no problem.