# Absolutely continuous iff continuous of bounded variation

Tags: measure-theory, continuity, lebesgue-measure, bounded-variation

I have the following problem (taken from q1 p341 of Kolmogorov and Fomin's Introductory Real Analysis), which I am struggling to prove completely. I think I know how to show the only if part, but not the rest:

Prove that a function $f$ is absolutely continuous on $[a,b]$ if and only if it is a continuous function of bounded variation mapping every subset $Z \subset [a,b]$ of measure zero into a set of measure zero.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you :)

Comment: There is a link to the proof in [Bounded variation implies Absolute Continuity](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/623379). It's somewhat tedious.

Comment: A proof for this can be found in Natanson - Theorie der Funktionen einer reellen Veränderlichen, Chapter IX, §3, Satz 4